# Kotlin 'when' - How to get lint warning in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, switch-statement

So I have many Enums in my app which get used in kotlins *when* calls.

For instance my enum class

```
enum class MyFancyEnum {
  TYPE_A,TYPE_B, TYPE_C
}
```

is used in something like this:

```
when (it){
 TYPE_A -> { ... }
}
```

What I need is a warning (or even better an error) in case I have forgotten to distinguish between all branches.

I can see, the compiler is highlighting this already and moving the cursor on it I get a message similar to that one:

> 'when' expression on enum is recommended to be exhaustive, add '...'
>   branch or 'else' branch instead

However, there are no lint checks for this in Android Studio. (One seems to be switch-case for Java but nothing similar for Kotlin).

**Question:**
How can I get a Lint Warning / Error in case I forgot one branch in a when expression?

Comment: You can add `.also { }` or `!!` to force `when` to be an expression.

Comment: Not exactly sure how it's meant to be with .also{}, but what I'd really like is to see all these cases in my code inspection. Hence the request for Lint warnings / errors.

Comment: When `when` is an expression, compiler will require you to cover all the possible cases.

Answer (score 2):

This is the workaround the was suggested in the comments: add an empty `.also{}` operator to the end of the `when` expression.

```
 when (it){
     TYPE_A -> { ... }
 }.also{}
```

This trick utilises the Kotlin compiler itself, which requires all branches of `when` to be covered if the result of the `when() { .. }` expression is used by someone. Since `.also{}` technically uses the result of the `when`, this triggers a compiler error.

Comment: Okay, well, this is a "solution". However, its not really perfect because I can already see developers forgetting to add this "arbitrary" also expression at the end disabling the check again. But thanks for one possible solution so far.

Comment: Exactly right. A Lint check would be better since you already use Lint. Unfortunately I don't now how to work with Lint :(

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using [sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html).

You can migrate your enum to sealed class, and use it like this:

```
sealed class MyFancyEnum {
   object TYPE_A : MyFancyEnum()
   object TYPE_B : MyFancyEnum()
   object TYPE_C : MyFancyEnum()
}

fun setFancyEnum(fancyEnum: MyFancyEnum) {
   when(fancyEnum) {
     is MyFancyEnum.TYPE_A -> ...
     is MyFancyEnum.TYPE_B -> ...    
  }
}
```

In that case, it won't even compile, because not all sealed class options are handled.

Comment: The idea sounds nice but to me it does compile. It just states a slightly different message now about sealed classes that should be exhaustive (instead of Enums). Am I missing something?

Comment: so I might get confused the way scala does it... anyway, the message means that not all the sealed class cases are covered in the `when` clause. because I suggested to "convert" your enum to sealed class, you got a warning which refers to a sealed class

Comment: In addition - take a look in this article - https://medium.com/fuzz/kotlin-features-you-should-use-now-62d246d80a53 and the sentence: `To allow our enum to hold state, but have the compiler verify we covered all cases of an instance, we change the declaration to a sealed class`

Comment: The is no substantial functional difference between sealed classes and enums, so refactoring ones into others will not change things

Comment: 10x for the clarification @voddan

Comment: Okay, so then there is little benefit (even though I guess I gonna use sealed classes for other benefits). However, if anyone has any idea on how to achieve a warning. After all, the compiler seams so see this problem anyway (I can also annotate in order to ignore it). So I assumed, there must be a way of enforcing it, too